# Create an advanced search that searches only on a field with search_api in drupal 7

Tags: search

I've successfully installed the [search api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module in drupal 7. I installed solar and it works fine. I need to create a custom search form that has various fields and those fields performs search only on the relitive field.

This means that if i have a content type with the following fields:

"job requested"

"previous exerience"

"city"

I want a searchh page with the same fields and when the user enter a value in the "city" field, it searches for that data only in that field: if I search the "city" field for "milan" I want to find only nodes with the word "milan" entered in the field "city" and not with the word "milan" entered in the body.

I think I need separete indexes for each fields, but structure the two forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need separated indexes. In you callback handler, you need to build a new [`SearchApiQueryInterface`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--search_api--includes--query.inc/interface/SearchApiQueryInterface/7) instance and set conditions on the field using its [`condition`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--search_api--includes--query.inc/function/SearchApiQueryInterface%3a%3acondition/7) method.

```
$index = search_api_index_load('custom_index_machine_name');
$query = $index->query(array(
  'language' => $GLOBALS['language']->language,
  'search id' => 'custom-search',
));
foreach($form_state['values']['filters'] as $field => $value) {
  if (!empty($value)) {
    $query->condition($field, $value);
  }
}
$result = $query->execute();
```